Is Mata Parvati a human or a goddess?
Since she is daughter of human king Parvata raja(is Parvata Raja human or devta?) Is Parvati ji human or a goddess(devi)?
Is she worshipable?
Especially what is the opinion of Madhvas and Vaishnavas on this issue?
Please give references..
